# Show background image through overlapping divs in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

Could anyone tell me if the scenario below would be achievable with HTML and CSS? My goal is to show the background-image of my HTML body through a clipped div.

[image]

Please bear in mind that the final website would be responsive (mobile-first), so the solution should allow the different positioning of the body background images upon resizing.

Basically: is there anyway to show a div as a cutout of the underlying div?

I thought about providing separate background images for each circle to show the illusion that the circles show the body background, but as the design is responsive, alignment issues would quickly occur.

Any insights? Please let me know if more data is necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way to achieve this is to put the same _background image_ to the _circle divs_ and play with `background-position` and `media querys`.

Comment: I'm thinking in the same direction, @Vucko , would have been great to be able if there was some magic clipping way. But it seems to go against the nature of the layers in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is similar:

http://ask.webatall.com/html5/7619_transparent-half-circle-cut-out-of-a-div.html

and should help? Instead of the shape you'd have to use circles, but the principle should be the same.
Also, if it doesn't work a combination of 2 elements with half circles cut out could achieve the effect.

This answer does a similar thing with another shape:

http://www.samhohce.net/questions/30259780/onhover-button-cut-out-a-triangle-and-show-background

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems fairly straightforward, using CSS-shapes. The only thing that's unclear to me is: how would I go about filling the rest of the screen below the header?

Comment: Do you mean the menu (Home, Kids etc..), or content of the cutout circles? Or below the circles?

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about filling the rest of the screen below the header with white, so as to create the illusion of the cirlces being cutouts?

Comment: If you think of this http://i.stack.imgur.com/EkDr6.png as a half circle within a rectangle it is straightforward: 
create one with the half circle on top, and a second one with the half circle at the bottom, then put the one with the half circle at the bottom over the one with the half circle at the top.

Comment: Creating the shapes is clear to me. The only issue is filling 100% of the viewport width with white, below the header.